# userが見ている画面のデータを取得できる方法ってあるんですか？

Tags: android

googleのOCRを使って、TEXTを取得できる方法もありますが、
userが見ている画面でアプリ情報やurlを分かる方法ってあるんですか？
教えてください。

Comment: バックグラウンドで動かしているあなたのアプリから、今ユーザーが使っているアプリの情報や、そのアプリで表示している内容を読み取ることができるか、という話でしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

※最初に注意しておきますが、具体的な解決策は書きません。いくつか問題があるためです。そのうえでのヒントになります。

解決のヒント：
　パケットをキャプチャして、レスポンスで取得しているHTMLの中からリンク情報を抜き出す方法が考えられます。（ただし簡単ではないと思いますし、いくつかクリアしなければいけない問題があります。）

問題点：
　プライバシー問題
　”ルート権なし”での”通信情報を取得する”ことが必要になると考えられますが、実装する際、プライバシー上の問題などを考慮する必要があります。例えばログイン情報を暗号化されず平文で転送していた場合、あなたのアプリは意図せずユーザの機密情報を手に入れることになり、あなたがそうでなくても、第三者がその情報を悪用するかもしれません。これは大変危険です。

私見：
　ルート権が通常は必要になるような情報にアクセスする必要がある場合、ルート権なしでの実装が技術上可能だとしても危険なものになり得ることを考慮した上で、質問内容は包括的かつ曖昧な内容ではなく、より具体的かつ論点を絞ったコード上の問題など、より技術的な質問をするべきだと思います。
　これによって不要に技術を悪用しようとする人を遠ざけることができます。